# Cant select dates in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

The simplest query in the world isnt working in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM "events"
  WHERE "date" >= datetime('2021-08-05T22:00:00') AND 
        "date" < datetime('2021-08-12T22:00:00');
```

The dates in the table as follows and I only receive last 2:

```
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-12T16:00:00
2021-09-10T16:00:00
2021-10-12T16:00:00
2021-11-09T17:00:00
2021-12-09T17:00:00
2021-08-11T16:00:00
2021-08-12 16:00:00
```

I inserted values by pasting simple text from notepad in SQLiteStudio v3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

If you execute:

```
datetime('2021-08-05T22:00:00')
```

the result is:

```
2021-08-05 22:00:00
```

Do you notice the missing `'T'`?

So, you are comparing strings (in SQLite dates are strings) and the comparison is alphabetical, but in the left side of the inequality you have a string with a `'T'` and in the right side a string without a `'T'`.

Either use the function `datetime()` in both sides of the inequality:

```
WHERE datetime("date") >= datetime('2021-08-05T22:00:00') 
  AND datetime("date") < datetime('2021-08-12T22:00:00')
```

or, don't use it at all:

```
WHERE "date" >= '2021-08-05T22:00:00' 
  AND "date" < '2021-08-12T22:00:00'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0e58af99ab1678c8c2d50fa7d649e65d).

Comment: nope. I tried that "dont use it at all" and without T from the beginning. didnt work either.. its what I said in my "answer" - the dates look like dates and they smell like dates but they are text in reality. since there is no typing in SQLite and SQLiteStudio (I guess) follows the pattern - you never can relax. Its a mine field.

Comment: P.S. after the fix - all version now work fine - with or without T, with or without `datetime` on one side or both.. doesnt matter

Comment: @BoppityBop check here that it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1dc3c0ecbd6b3c14a34974d51cf47f34

Comment: @BoppityBop the last row of your data does not have 'T'.

Comment: After I converted text to dates in the db column (see my answer) - everything works - with or without T

Comment: @BoppityBop well done. But the values are still text. The format with 'T' is an accepted format of timestamps in SQLite as you can find in the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values. The problem is that the function datetime() function that you used when you had the 'T's returns string datetimes without the 'T's and this inconsistency did not provide the correct output.

Answer (score -1):

I think its "by design". SQLiteStudio doesnt bother to check types. So if you paste text then you get text in Date field. You have to post-process dates by hand:

```
update "events" set "date" = datetime("date");
```

**EDIT** to clarify. The following statements did not produce correct result before `update` and are producing correct result after the `update`

```
SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE "date" >= datetime('2021-08-05T22:00:00') AND "date" < datetime('2021-08-12T22:00:00');
SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE "date" >= datetime('2021-08-05 22:00:00') AND "date" < datetime('2021-08-12 22:00:00');
SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE "date" >= '2021-08-05T22:00:00' AND "date" < '2021-08-12T22:00:00';
SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE "date" >= '2021-08-05 22:00:00' AND "date" < '2021-08-12 22:00:00';
```

Comment: There is no DATE or DATETIME type in SQLite, although you can use it to define a column. Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: i edited the answer. make a table with date field, paste text into it using SQLiteStudio run these statements, then run the `update` and run the selects again. The bottom line is - it doesnt matter if there is T or not and if there is datetime or not - if data is not "right" - nothing works.. what is right ? Idk - ask SQLiteStudio devs.